# Route group with multiple middleware checks

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-route

In my laravel project i have made my own roles and added them to middleware so i can use *auth.admin* or *auth.superadmin* to protect specific routes.

I have a Route::Group for my super admin role, a Route::Group for my admin role and a Route:Group for the standard auth check.

Now i have a specific Route that has to be accessed by the superadmin and the admin. 
When i place the route in the admin group OR the superadmin group it works. But when i try to place it in both or make a route group where i check for both roles it doesnt. 
Then i tried making a Route::Group like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','auth.admin', 'auth.superadmin']], function() {
        Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['except' => ['show']]);
});
```

I was thought this would fix my problem but it didnt.

How can i make a Route Group where only admins and superadmins can acces the route.

Comment: Create a new middleware that checks if user has either of roles.

Comment: this should work. what error you are getting??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I thought it would work, i dont get any error but i get redirected to /home. Is i place the route in one of the role groups it works but if i combine them they both dont work, i just get redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your middleware to use a setup like this:

```
Route::get('/home', ['middleware' => 'roles:admin,superadmin', function () {
   echo '/home';
}]);
```

And then using the `...` operator you can easily check the parameter `$roles` as an array:

```
// YourMiddleware.php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
```

Comment: I understand that this option might work. I might be stubborn but i would like to know why my solution doesnt work. Just so i can learn from it.

Comment: well first of all you are duplicating logic in your middleware. They are both checking for a role. Next: middleware is run in series, which means that if `auth.admin` fails (the user is not an admin), then that middleware redirects to a 403 page for instance. You cant and shouldnt do `OR` comparisons between middleware.